# drawing vertical line using hr tag or div

Tags: html, css

I am wondering which is a best practice to use if I have to draw vertical line using HTML `<hr>` tag or using `<div>` tag. `div` will probably require the usage of css I believe and with `hr` tag, one can achieve the same thing with something like this : `<hr width="1" size="500">`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Still I am wondering if there is any preference of using one over another?

Comment: You might also use border attributes on the elements you want visually separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi dear  see this code i think useful for you

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qvdbr6c/)

### **CSS**

```
 .pk{
    height: 500px;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>happy diwali</div>
<div class="pk"></div>
```

Comment: Well that line is horizontal, not vertical

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh sorry dear

Answer (score 1):

All depends on the context of use. Even with the tag `<hr>` CSS does not do without if you want an acceptable form of vertical bars.

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: It may be necessary to use the elements as intended? W3C: The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g. a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book.